# Ball bounces outside boundary

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the updated version of my program in previous question.
Currently I am trying to determine why my maxTop variable that monitors the top and bottom of my box div returns a **NaN value**.

When I run my program the ball bounces on the left and right walls but leaves when it reaches the bottom/top walls. Any suggestions as to why?

My variables are as follows:

```
currentLeftPos = parseInt($("#ball").css('left'));
currentTopPos = parseInt($("#ball").css('top'));

// define the new position
var newLeftPos = currentLeftPos + velocity_x;

//alert(velocity_x);
var newTopPos = currentTopPos + velocity_y;

//alert(velocity_y);
// If the left position is greater than or equal to the maximum distance allowed or

//   less than or equal to zero, then change the direction.

if( newLeftPos >= maxLeft || newLeftPos <= 0)
    velocity_x *= -1; // multiply the value by -1

if( newTopPos >= maxTop || newTopPos <= 0)
    velocity_y *= -1; // multiply the value by -1

maxLeft = parseInt($("#outerbox").css('width')) -parseInt($("#outerbox").css('border-left-width')) - parseInt($("#ball").css('width'));

maxTop =  parseInt($("#outerbox").css('top')) -parseInt($("#outerbox").css('border-left-top')) - parseInt($("#ball").css('top'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/4884/

Comment: It's 'border-top-width' instead of border-top-height

Comment: Debugging it isn't that hard, showing you that `border-top-height` is undefined. There is no CSS property like that

Comment: In cases like this where your result is unexpected, it can often be helpful to take each piece of the equation and console.log() it to make sure you are getting what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `border-top-width` instead of `border-top-height` will the solution of your first **NAN** issue.

And solution for your second issue is:

```
var maxRight = parseInt($("#outerbox").css('width')) +maxLeft;
var maxBottom =  parseInt($("#outerbox").css('height')) - parseInt($("#ball").css('height'));
```

Update upper value When change dimension And:

```
if( newTopPos >= maxBottom || newTopPos <= 0)
   velocity_y *= -1; // multiply the value by -1

 if( newTopPos >= maxRight || newTopPos <= 0)
   velocity_y *= -1; // multiply the value by -1
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/4890/)

Comment: What is funny is that before I tried implementing a bottom but since my one line of code of maxLeft worked for left and right I thought one line would work for top and bottom. Thank you for explaining this!

Answer (score 1):

There is no property border height

```
var maxTop =  parseInt($("#outerbox").css('height')) -parseInt($("#outerbox").css('border-top-width')) - parseInt($("#ball").css('height'));

alert(maxTop);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-width.asp

[image]

UPDATE:
A working jsfiddle to demonstrate how to bounce a ball within a box, it show how to create a basic bounce ball game

http://jsfiddle.net/49qd7q8h/2/

Comment: I wasn't completely familiar with the border properties so it is good to know all the different ones. I appreciate showing me this!

Comment: I just update my answer with a jsfiddle see how it works, it will show you how to create a basic bounce ball game